# Stuck at making a database insert class function

Tags: php, pdo

Iam trying to make a OOP based forum in PHP and currently im stuck at making the Database class. Specifically Iam stuck at making a "general purpose" insert class function for the Datatable class (using PDO btw).

```
class DB
            {
                private $dbconn;

                public function __construct(){

                }

                protected function connect($dbname,  $dbhost='127.0.0.1', $dbuser='root', $dbpass=''){

                    try{
                     $this->dbconn = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname;", $dbuser, $dbpass, array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'UTF8'"));
                    }

                    catch(PDOException $e){
                        echo 'Connection failed: '.$e->getMessage()."<br />";
                    }
                }

                protected function disconnect(){
                    $this->dbconn = null;
                }

                public function insert($dbname, ){
                     $this->connect($dbname);

                    try{
                        # prepare
                        $sql = "INSERT INTO pdodemotable (firstname, lastname, age, reg_date) 
                          VALUES (?, ?, ?, now())";
                        $stmt = $dbconn->prepare($sql);
                        # the data we want to insert
                        $data = array($firstname, $lastname, $age);
                        # execute width array-parameter
                        $stmt->execute($data);

                        echo "New record created successfully";
                    }
                    catch(PDOException $e){
                        echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
                    }
                }
            }
```

The insert function is as you see unfinished. I cant figure out how to get the insert function to adapt to ANY amount of arguments, ANY amount of database columns and ANY table. The code thats in the function right now is taken from one of my other projects where I used procedural programming. Its by first time using OOP with Databases.

Im a newbie to both OOP and PDO. There must be some sort of method or function that could help me that Im missing. The only solution I see right now is to use a ridicoulus amount of string handling and if statement... it cant be the best solution... there must be a easier way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First notice - you don't need the `$dbname` parameter for insert method, instead it should be a constructor parameter:

```
class DB {

    private $dbconn;

    public function __construct($dbname, $dbhost='127.0.0.1', $dbuser='root', $dbpass='') {
        // also don't catch the error here, let it propagate, you will clearly see
        // what happend from the original exception message
        $this->dbconn = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname;", $dbuser, $dbpass, array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'UTF8'"));
    }

    ...

}
```

As for the `insert` method - first try to imagine how it will be used.
For example, it can be like this:

```
$db = new DB('mydb');
$db->insert('mytable', array('firstname'=>'Pete', 'lastname'=>'Smith'));
```

Then you can pass the table name and data (keys/values) into the method:

```
public function insert($table, $data) {
    // again, no need to try / catch here, let the exceptions
    // do their job
    // handle errors only in the case you are going to fix them
    // and not just to ingnore them and 'echo', this can lead to much worse problems
    // see the explanation below regarding the `backtick` method
    $table = $this->backtick($table);
    $fields = array();
    $placeholders = array();
    $values = array();
    foreach($data as $key=>$value) {
        $fields[] = $this->backtick($key);
        // you can also process some special values like 'now()' here
        $placeholders[] = '?';
    }
    $fields = implode($fields, ','); // firstname, lastname
    $placeholders = implode($placeholders, ','); // ?, ?
    $sql = "INSERT INTO $table ($fields) values ($placeholders)";
    $stmt = $this->dbconn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute(array_values($data));
}


public function update($table, $id, $data) {
    $table = $this->backtick($table);
    $fields = array();
    foreach($data as $key=>$value) {
        $fields[] = $this->backtick($key) . " = ?";
    }
    $fields = implode($fields, ','); // firstname=?, lastname=?
    $sql = "UPDATE $table SET $fields where id=?";
    $stmt = $this->dbconn->prepare($sql);
    $data['id'] = $id;
    $stmt->execute(array_values($data));
    if ($stmt->execute(array_values($data)) === false) {
        print 'Error: ' . json_encode($stmt->errorInfo()). PHP_EOL;
    }
    while ($row = $stmt->fetchAll()) {
        print json_encode($row) . PHP_EOL;
    }
}

private function backtick($key) {
    return "`".str_replace("`","``",$key)."`";
}
```

Another alternative is to create the separate object which will represent one table row (the [ActiveRecord](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_record_pattern) pattern).
The code which uses such object could look like this:

```
$person = new Person($db);
$person->firstName = 'Pete';
$person->lastName = 'Smith';
$person->save(); // insert or update the table row
```

**Update on possible SQL injection vulnerability**

I also added the `update` and `backtick` methods to illustrate the possible SQL injection.
Without the `backtick`, it is possible that `update` will be called with something like this:

```
$db->updateUnsafe('users', 2, array(
    "name=(SELECT'bad guy')WHERE`id`=1#"=>'', 
    'name'=>'user2', 'password'=>'text'));
```

Which will lead to the SQL statement like this:

```
UPDATE users SET name=(SELECT'bad guy')WHERE`id`=1# = ?,name = ?,password = ? where id=?
```

So instead of updating the data for user with id 2, we it will change the name for the user with id 1.
Due to `backtick` method, the statement above will fail with `Unknown column 'name=(SELECT'bad guy')WHERE`id`=2#' in 'field list'`.
[Here is](https://github.com/serebrov/so-questions/blob/7c5579aae6c03e5e16e299f79c6c5f393e3eb9ed/quick-test/php-test-db-pdo-sql-injection.php) the full code of my test.

Anyway, this probably will not protect you from any possible SQL injection, so the it is much better not to use the user input for known parameters like table name and field names.

Instead of doing something like `$db->insert('mytable', $_POST)`, do `$db->insert('mytable', array('first'=>$_POST['first']))`.

Comment: [This code is essentially vulnerable to SQL injection.](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/lame_update)

Comment: @YourCommonSense it is vulnerable if `$keys` in the data are coming from the user, like if we do `$db->insert('mytable', $_POST)` and pass the whole `$_POST` array as a data, right? But if we do something like `$db->insert('mytable', array('first'=>$_POST['first']))` then it should be OK. Also is the only thing which can be done here is quoting? Can we just add $this->dbconn->quote() for table name and keys to make it safe?

Comment: No, we can't use string quoting for identifiers, it will result in a syntax error. At the very least you have to format identifiers, but better to whitelist them.

Comment: @YourCommonSense I updated my answer with the escaping by backticks (stolen from your article) and added a note regarding SQL injection. I think there are still some cases when this code can be vulnerable, but at least there is a warning, thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score -1):

Try to pass the arguments has an array, then, inside the method insert, do a foreach.

Something like:

```
$data['first_name'] = 'your name';
...
$data['twentieth_name'] = 'twentieth name';

foreach( $data as $key => $value )
    $final_array[':'.$key] = $value;

$stmt->execute( $final_array );
```